# PHP Classes - call one class function from another

Tags: php, class

I have a function in a class with this code:

```
$this -> userDb;
$error = $this -> error;
print_r($error);
```

userDb is another function in this class and error is generated by userDb. It always gives a non-empty array.

Why wouldn't I be able to get the value of $this -> error?

Comment: Try posting the whole class, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First userDb is function but you aren't calling the function. You have to call userDb as

`$this->userDb();`

Comment: I think I was getting VB syntex mixed in there

Answer (score 0):

to call a method (function) you must use parentheses:

```
$this->userDb();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code for the `userDb` function, it's difficult to explain why the error is caused. However, if you're trying to call the function, you need to include the brackets in the function call:

```
$this->userDb();
print_r($this->error);
```